# Восклицательный знак Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в данном случае восклицательный знак, означает НЕ. То есть НЕ больше минус одного?

```
'''
if (!$.inArray(index, used_cards) > -1) {

}
'''
```

Comment: Нет, в данном случае восклицательный знак означает какую-то чепуху.

Comment: А что означает сочетание `!$` в Jquery в принципе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Восклицательный знак никакого отношения к jQuery не имеет. Он означает логическое отрицание примененное к операнду, непосредственно следующему за ним. То есть операнд преобразуется в булевское значение, а потом берется его отрицание.

```js
console.log(!-1);
console.log(!0);
console.log(!1);
```

В Вашем выражении, вероятно, пропущены скобки.

```
if (!($.inArray(index, used_cards) > -1)) {

}
```

Comment: То есть в данном случае, выражение будет воспринято, как истинное, если условие окажется ложным, верно?

Comment: @NikitaMigushev Да, если добавить скобки.

Comment: Все понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Хотя то же самое можно записать, как `if ($.inArray(index, used_cards) == -1) {

}`